# Regex match permutation with missing elements

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I want to match any permutation of a group of characters but allow any to be missing.

For example, if I can choose from `abc` valid matches would be "", "a", "ba", "cab". Invalid matches would be "aa", "abcc", "bbbbbb".

`a?b?c?` is my best guess but it doesn't allow for permutations, and I'm looking for a way to generalize this to any group.

Comment: Sort the string before running regex.

Comment: What do I do from there? Also, is it possible to do with pure regex?

Comment: From there you do a?b?c?

Comment: For your sample you could probably use something like [`^(?:([abc])(?!.*?\1))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/lqBai2/1) but the other idea sounds better.